# storing data common to more than one view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I know there are many ways for storing data like property list,archiving etc..but other than that is there any  other way for storing very small amount of data,which is common to different view controllers(like a common class for storing all the data)?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do it by creating a singleton class and shared instance

Answer (score 2):

Try this

## NSUserDefaults

```
when you want to save small amounts of data such as High Scores, Login Information, and program state.
```

## saving

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// saving an NSInteger
[prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"integerKey"];

// saving a Double
[prefs setDouble:3.1415 forKey:@"doubleKey"];

// saving a Float
[prefs setFloat:1.2345678 forKey:@"floatKey"];

[prefs synchronize];

## Retrieving

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// getting an NSInteger
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];

// getting an Float
float myFloat = [prefs floatForKey:@"floatKey"];

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define the required fields in form of an array. Now make sure that the form will provide you an identity and there is some validation through session etc. A a hook to your controller to sense the form submission every time with a particular flag (hidden). So the tablename and CRUD instruction will be provided to this function and every common CRUD functionality will be handled by this single function. By defining the required fields will let you ignore the extra ones like input buttons and many hidden fields.

Answer (score 1):

use `NSUserDefault` to store values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can declare in forms of NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary and access it any Viewcontrollers. You need to create a file as NSObject class and in

.h

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)ImageCollection;
```

in .m file

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)ImageCollection
{
static NSMutableDictionary *thestring =nil;

@synchronized([Global class]) // in a single threaded app you can omit the sync block
{

    if (thestring ==nil) {
        thestring=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    }
}
return thestring;

}
```

In any View Controllers include that NSObject class file

```
  [[Global ImageCollection]setObject:@"Sample" forKey:@"Dictionary"];  //just example you can save string,image,array anything as you like
```

Hope this helps .. !!!

Comment: Actually ,I have created a recipe app.I am using storyboard and i have five view controllers for showing data.I am passing data to different viewcontollers using segue.So my problem is, for presenting data in a view controller i have to store data meant for that view controller in previous view controller.So in certain situations i have to store same data in different view controllers which cause repetition of data.

And i tried to place all the data in one view controller class and tried to access those datas from other view controllers by creating objects but it fails by returning null..

Answer (score 0):

Use shared memory, to store and share common data between views.